# Trouble understanding void arrays and using them in function calls

Tags: c, random, void

i'm attempting a question which asks me to create a function called randSwap, that takes in 2 arrays of void pointers, and with a 50% chance, it will swap 2 values of the same index between the 2 arrays. Below is my code, but whenever i go to compile, it gives me several errors discussing:

warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast.

```
void *array1[4] = {3,4,2,5};
```

and several others relating to array1 and 2.

When i run the program, the values of array1 becomes corrupted producing a large single integer, and array 2 prints its original values both times.

I am very unfamiliar with using void types, as I think this is where the problem lies.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int randSwap(void *array1[], void *array2[], int length)
{
    static int numofswaps = 0;
    int value;
    int toswap;
    void *temp;


    value = rand() % 2;
    if(value == 2)
    {
        toswap = rand() % length;
        temp = array1[toswap];
        array1[toswap] = array2[toswap];
        array2[toswap] = temp;

        numofswaps++; 
    }

    return numofswaps;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    void *array1[4] = {3,4,2,5};
    void *array2[4] = {6,3,7,4};
    int length = 4;
    int numofswaps;
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Array1\n");
    for(i=0; i<length; i++);
    {

        printf("%d\t", (int*)array1[i]);
    }

    printf("\nArray2\n");
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", (int*)array2[i]);
    }

    numofswaps = randSwap(array1, array2, length);
    numofswaps = randSwap(array1, array2, length);

    printf("\nArray1\n");
    for(i=0; i<length; i++);
    {

        printf("%d\t", (int*)array1[i]);
    }

    printf("\nArray2\n");
    for(i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", (int*)array2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In the `main` function you declare e.g. `array1` as an array of pointer to `void`, but you don't initialize it with valid pointers? What are you really trying to do? What is the purpose of the arrays? Why do you initialize them with `int` values instead of pointers?

Comment: `*array1[4]` is an *array of pointers* [4 of them],  `= {3,4,2,5};` is an initialization to 4 `int` values. (*int value* is not equal to *a pointer*).

Comment: the question has asked me to use 'arrays of void pointers' as parameters in the function randSwap. I'm not sure why... and i'm not sure how to do this. If i use just 'array1[4]' i get an error that says 'error: declaration of array1 as array of voids'.

Comment: @L.Kay You need to decide what you want the arrays to contain.  If the elements are void pointers, i.e. `void *`, then they must hold pointers of some type.  The question is, pointers to what?  That it something you must answer.

Comment: In other words declare `int array1 = {3,4,2,5}..`, then pass the array to the function as a `void *` (you will then need to cast in your function before you dereference -- like in a `qsort` compare function)

Comment: It seems more likely that the assignment asked you for the swap function to take just two void pointers (not arrays), each of which points at an element of an array

Comment: `for(i=0; i<length; i++);` causes undefined behavior in the next line.

Comment: Using `%` with `rand` is problematic because legacy implementations of `rand` are very poor in the low bits. An easy fix is to switch to `random` if your implementation has it. Otherwise, you can get a “good” random bit from `rand` by using `rand() <= RAND_MAX/2`. That can have a slight bias due to `RAND_MAX` being odd, but it is likely better than `rand() % 2`. For more than a [0, 1] choice, you need to do some arithmetic to take the high part of the return value of `rand`, not the low part.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is initialize an array of `void` pointers with array of integers

```
   void *array1[4] = {3,4,2,5};
```

Essentially trying to assign an integer to a pointer. Hence the warning -

> warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Rest warning might be because of improper declaration of these variables. Now, you mention in the comments that the question asks you to define the function `randSwap` with exactly this type. This could be because they want a general interface.

So what you can do is, make your array also contain pointers to integers as -

```
void *array1[4] = {&(int){3}, &(int){4}, &(int){2}, &(int){5}};
```

This will create `int` literals and you can take addresses of them.

You will also have to change your `printf` to -

```
printf("%d\n", *(int*)array1[i]); // Add * to dereference the pointer.
```

This will make your code work fine.

Finally some other error I saw with your code -

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++);
```

This sets the value of `i` to 4 and it ends up doing out of bound access in the next line.

You probably need

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
```

Comment: On the wording "*is assign an array*": Arrays ***cannot*** be assigned in C. What the OP's code is doing is called "initialise an array".

Comment: @alk the for loop has a `;` at the end. All it does it sets `i` to `len`

Answer (score 0):

You have a large number of small problems in your code. Continuing from my comments, you are attempting to initialize an *array of pointers[4]* with 4-`int` values. Instead of attempting to declare `array1` and `array2` as void, simply declare them as `int[]` and pass them as `void*` to `randSwap`, e.g.

```
    int i,
        array1[] = {3, 4, 2, 5},
        array2[] = {6, 3, 7, 4},
        length = sizeof array1 / sizeof *array1,
        numofswaps = 0;
```

Next in `numSwaps`, your use of `modulo` (`%`) is off by one:

```
    value = rand() % 2;     /* produces value 0 - 1 */
    if (value == 2)         /* will never equal 2 */
```

You need nothing more than a test of `0` or `1`, e.g.

```
    value = rand() % 2;     /* produces value 0 - 1 */
    if (value)              /* either 0 or 1 */
    {
        ...
```

Don't declare, `numofswaps` as `static` in `randSwap`, instead, declare it as a simple `int` in `main()` and pass it as a parameter to `randSwap`.

To handle the arrays in `numSwap` passed as `void *`, you need to cast them to `int*` before attempting to access their values to avoid an attempt to dereference a `void` pointer (not allowed). You can do something similar to:

```
int randSwap (void *array1, void *array2, int length, int ns)
{
    int value,
        toswap,
        temp,
        *a1 = (int*)array1, /* note: the explicit casts are optional, the */
        *a2 = (int*)array2; /* declaration of a1 & a2 as int* is sufficient */

    value = rand() % 2;     /* produces value 0 - 1 */
    // if (value == 2)         /* will never equal 2 */
    if (value)              /* either 0 or 1 */
    {
        toswap = rand() % length;
        temp = a1[toswap];
        a1[toswap] = a2[toswap];
        a2[toswap] = temp;

        ns++; 
    }

    return ns;
}
```

(`ns` representing `numofswaps` -- I don't like typing...)

Putting all the pieces together, you could rework you code to something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for rand() and srand() */
#include <time.h>   /* for time() */

int randSwap (void *array1, void *array2, int length, int ns)
{
    int value,
        toswap,
        temp,
        *a1 = array1,
        *a2 = array2;

    value = rand() % 2;     /* produces value 0 - 1 */
    // if (value == 2)         /* will never equal 2 */
    if (value)              /* either 0 or 1 */
    {
        toswap = rand() % length;
        temp = a1[toswap];
        a1[toswap] = a2[toswap];
        a2[toswap] = temp;

        ns++; 
    }

    return ns;
}

int main (void)
{
    int i,
        array1[] = {3, 4, 2, 5},
        array2[] = {6, 3, 7, 4},
        length = sizeof array1 / sizeof *array1,
        numofswaps = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf ("Array1\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf (" %d", array1[i]);

    printf("\nArray2\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf (" %d", array2[i]);

    numofswaps = randSwap (array1, array2, length, numofswaps);
    numofswaps = randSwap (array1, array2, length, numofswaps);

    printf ("\nArray1\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf (" %d", array1[i]);

    printf ("\nArray2\n");
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
        printf(" %d", array2[i]);

    // putchar ('\n');     /* don't printf a single-character */
    printf ("\n\nnumber of swaps: %d\n", numofswaps);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** you have not output `numofswaps` in `main()`, I added that at the end for you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
 $ ./bin/ptrswap
Array1
 3 4 2 5
Array2
 6 3 7 4
Array1
 6 4 2 5
Array2
 3 3 7 4

number of swaps: 1
```

As a further refinement to `randSwap`, there is no need to declare `numofswaps` as `static` and no need to pass it as a parameter. All you need to do is have `randSwap` return either `0` or `1` to indicate whether a swap took place and sum the swaps back in `main()`, e.g.

```
int randSwap (void *array1, void *array2, int length)
{
    int toswap, temp,
        *a1 = array1,
        *a2 = array2;

    if (rand() % 2) {   /* either 0 or 1 */
        toswap = rand() % length;
        temp = a1[toswap];
        a1[toswap] = a2[toswap];
        a2[toswap] = temp;

        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and then in `main()`,

```
    if (randSwap (array1, array2, length))
        numofswaps++;
    if (randSwap (array1, array2, length))
        numofswaps++;
```

(**note:** that is the cleaner way to handle it -- same output)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The `void**` was unnecessary, I reworked to just swap `int`. If swapping pointers is a hard requirement, then you would still pass `void *`, but the cast would be handled differently. -- There is no UB in the code above. It's just another way to approach it that avoids the *address of literal* creativity.

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that you also changed the declaration of the `randSwap` function. I think this is okay if the question allows flexibility in the declaration.

Comment: No problem. I thought about initializing an array of pointers to the elements of the `int` arrays, but that just really over-complicated the scenario. The Questioner may be wanting to swap pointers, but given the level of the question and problems, I suspect the requirement is to pass an `int` array as `void*` and handle the swap.

Comment: Agreed. OP might have interpreted the question in a wrong way. Anyway standard `qsort` also does it in a same way.

Comment: `(ns representing numofswaps -- I don't like typing...)`, but then you typed all that :^)

Comment: Yes, when I use something cryptic, I start to feel bad that it may throw them for a loop -- and usually end up typing more to explain... `:p`